# Is there a name for this pattern "type 'a foldedSequence = Empty | Value of 'a * (unit->'a foldedSequence )"

Tags: f#

I have been working with some f# parsers and some streaming software and I find myself using this pattern more and more. I find it to be a natural alternative to sequences and it has some natural advantages.
here are some example functions using the type.

```
type foldedSequence<'a> = 
    | Empty
    | Value of ' a * (unit -> 'a foldedSequence)

let rec createFoldedSequence fn state = 
    match fn state with
    | None -> Empty
    | Some(value, nextState) ->
        Value(value, (fun () -> unfold fn nextState))

let rec filter predicate = 
    function 
    | Empty -> Empty
    | Value(value, nextValue) -> 
        let next() = filter predicate(nextValue())
        if predicate value then Value(value, next)
        else next()

let toSeq<'t> = 
    Seq.unfold<'t foldedSequence, 't>(function 
        | Empty -> None
        | Value(value, nextValue) -> Some(value, nextValue()))
```

It has been very helpful I would like to know if it has a name so I can research some tips and tricks for it

Comment: FWIW, "predecate" should probably be "predicate" ;)

Comment: which type are you asking about, the one in the title or the other one, in the question body? that last one is a stream, which is either empty, or a pair holding the current value and the function to produce the next stream.

Comment: Sorry I mistyped in the header I am asking about the stream `type foldedSequence<'a> =  Empty | Value of ' a * (unit -> 'a foldedSequence)`

Comment: try coinductive lazy streams.

Comment: Cannot seem to find anything on it. 

I find it very useful I'm surprised it doesn't have a name.

Comment: googling "coinductive stream", "coinductive lazy streams f#" etc. finds stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add to the existing answers, I think Haskellers might call a generalised version of this this [a list monad transformer](https://wiki.haskell.org/ListT_done_right). The idea is that your type definition looks almost like ordinary F# `list` except that there is some additional aspect to it. You can imagine writing this as:

```
type ListTransformer<'T> = 
   | Empty
   | Value of 'T * M<ListTransformer<'T>>
```

By supplying specific `M`, you can define a number of things:

- `M<'T> = 'T` gives you the ordinary F# list type
- `M<'T> = unit -> 'T` gives you your sequence that can be evaluated lazily
- `M<'T> = Lazy<'T>` gives you LazyList (which caches already evaluated elements)
- `M<'T> = Async<'T>` gives you [asynchronous sequences](http://tomasp.net/blog/async-sequences.aspx/)

It is also worth noting that in this definition `LazyTransformer<'T>` is not itself a delayed/lazy/async value. This can cause problems in some cases - e.g. when you need to perform some async operation to decide whether the stream is empty - and so a better definition is:

```
type ListTransformer<'T> = M<ListTransformerInner<'T>>
and ListTransformerInner<'T> =
   | Empty
   | Value of 'T * ListTransformer<'T>
```

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was after. I'm still new to functional type systems and I never considered using a generic monoid to wrap the continuation value.

Comment: @ThomasDevries Happy this helped! You cannot quite do this generically in F# as there is no way to parameterize type by another parameterized type (i.e. make this generic over `M`), but I think this is still quite useful as a general design pattern (plus, I think that treating this just as a design pattern makes you think harder about designing it well for the specific use case you have in mind).

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like `LazyList` which used to be in the "powerpack" and I think now lives here:

http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpx.Collections/reference/fsharpx-collections-lazylist-1.html

https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpx.Collections/blob/master/src/FSharpx.Collections/LazyList.fs

Answer (score 1):

Your type is close to how an iteratee would be defined, and since you already mention streaming, this might be the concept you're looking for.

Iteratee IO is an approach to lazy IO outlined by [Oleg Kiselyov](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/Iteratee/). Apart from Haskell, implementations exist for major functional languages, including F# (as part of [FSharpx.Extras](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpx.Extras/blob/master/src/FSharpx.Extras/Iteratee.fs)).

This is how FSharpx defines an `Iteratee`:

```
type Iteratee<'Chunk,'T> =
    | Done of 'T * Stream<'Chunk>
    | Error of exn
    | Continue of (Stream<'Chunk> -> Iteratee<'Chunk,'T>)
```

See also this blog post: [Iteratee in F# - part 1](https://wizardsofsmart.wordpress.com/2011/10/10/iteratee-in-f-part-1/). Note that there doesn't seem to be a part 2.